Simulation Time in Concurrent VHDL Procedures
Simulating in EdaPlayground the following code,
gives me the simulation results below the code

--CONCURRENT PROCEDURE CALL TIMING PROBLEM
ENTITY tb IS
END ENTITY tb;

ARCHITECTURE sim OF tb IS
  SIGNAL cnt  : integer RANGE 0 TO 3 := 0;
  SIGNAL str  : string(1 TO 5) := (OTHERS => ' ');
 
  PROCEDURE test (CONSTANT number  : IN integer RANGE 0 TO 3 := 0;
                  SIGNAL   num_str : OUT string(1 TO 5)) IS
  BEGIN
 
  
    CASE number IS
      WHEN 0      => num_str <= "zero "; REPORT "Zero";
      WHEN OTHERS => num_str <= "one  "; REPORT "One";
    END CASE;
  END PROCEDURE;
  
BEGIN
  test(cnt, str);  -- CONCURRENT CALL TO PROCEDURE TEST
  
 PROCESS 
 BEGIN
 
  
  FOR i IN 0 TO 3 LOOP
    WAIT FOR 10 ns;   --this timing is not OK. Second transaction is @20ns WHY not @10ns
     cnt <= i;
     --WAIT FOR 10 ns;  --this timing is OK
  END LOOP;
 WAIT;
 END PROCESS;
 
 ----Process
-- begin
 --wait until cnt'transaction;
 --report "*******************Transaction happen at report current time = " & time'image(now);
 --end process;
 
END ARCHITECTURE sim;

My question is, why simulation Time advances 0ns,20ns, 30ns, 40ns  and not
0ns, 10ns, 20ns, 30ns ?
If i move the  'WAIT FOR 10 ns;' after cnt <=i; simulation timing looks correct.
Is it some sort of race condition?

This is the timing reported by Eda Playground:# run -all
** Note: Zero
Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb
** Note: One
Time: 20 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb
** Note: One
Time: 30 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb
** Note: One
Time: 40 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb
exit

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it is not a forum, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add the addition you made in a comment.

The simulation algorithm consists of an initialisation phase, followed by a repeated simulation cycle. During initialisation cnt is driven with 0, and all processes will run until they suspend.
So, what does that actually mean? First, your test procedure is sensitive to cnt, and so wakes up, and reports 'Zero', at time 0.
Second, your process runs until the wait statement, and suspends. It's scheduled to wake up at 10ns. Initialisation is now complete, and the simulation cycle starts. At 10ns the process resumes, and assigns 0 to cnt; however, cnt is already 0, so nothing happens. The loop repeats, and it suspends at the wait, and is scheduled to resume at 20ns. At 20ns it resumes, and drives cnt with 1. The procedure is sensitive to this change, executes, and reports 'One' at time 20.

Thanks EML. Above is true. I came to the same conclusion by reading the LRM which states that a concurrent procedure is equivalent to a process( without sensitivity list, that calls the procedure and at the end suspends with a wait on  statement. So in essence, the above concurrent procedure call is equivalent to.
PROCESS
 BEGIN
   test(cnt, str);  
 WAIT ON cnt;
 END
END PROCESS

So At time = 0ns, Process executes with the initial default value of cnt :=0 and halts at wait on statement during initialization. The Loop halts as well at time o ns during initialization to wait for 10ns and after 10ns, cnt is updated in the loop to 0(as the loop runs 0 to 3). But the new value of 0 ns does not trigger WAIT ON cnt; statement as there is no event change from the previous cnt state(cnt :=0 previous and cnt =0 is the new state), so the process is not activated and still "waits on". The loop then goes back to wait for another 10 ns(that is the second iteration). after 10ns ( 20ns total now) cnt is assigned a value of 1 in the for loop. The Wait ON statement detects the change of value from the previous state (cnt =0 to 1) and triggers the process. The process is re activated and the test procedure executes with a cnt=1 and then stops again at the wait on statement, waiting for another change of the cnd parameter. This last process execution lasts one delta cycle ( e.g zero added simulation time) .At that point the simulatin time is at 20ns, essentially skipping the first 10ns due to no change of cnt events.
